# How to rotate PDF file using tkdocviewer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to rotate a PDF file that is displayed on tkinter.

[Link here to module](https://pypi.org/project/tkDocViewer/) I had to also install ghostcript for the PDF file to display on tkinter window.

My current code here (coppied from the module document):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkdocviewer import *

# Create a root window
root = Tk()

# Create a DocViewer widget
v = DocViewer(root)
v.pack(side="top", expand=1, fill="both")

# Display some document
v.display_file("test.pdf")

# Start Tk's event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Displays an image vertically to the right. I need to rotate it 90 degrees clockwise and display it that way.

Is this possible? or is this module not the best for this scenario?

Comment: You can do: load the image `v.display_path`, rotate it, save it back, call `v.reload()`

Comment: Why tag this with Ghostscript, when you want to use 'tkdocviewer' ? Ghostscript tag removed.

Comment: @KenS becasue GhostScipt is required for this module

Comment: Nevertheless, that doesn't make it a Ghostscrit question. Presumably you also needed Windows or Linux in order to run your program as well.